# Mac Terminal: Loop through subdirectories and optimise all images

Tags: macos, terminal, images, image-editing

I have a folder containing many subfolders full of images. See attached image for example.

[image: alt]

Basically I want to loop through them all and downsize the images so none are wider than 1024 pixels. They're all jpegs.

I'm aware of the SIPS commands i.e.

```
sips -Z 1024 *.png
```

However, that only works if all images are in the current directory.

How do I set it up to traverse through all subdirectories?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run it with find: `find images/path -type f -name '*.png' -exec sips -Z 1024 {} \;`

Find will search for files (-type f), with png extension (-name '*.png') inside 'images/path' directory and exec the command in parameter, replacing "{}" with the filename, you need to end the command with "\;".

Comment: Thanks. I had some issue with that not actually resizing all but did the same with imagemagick: `find /images/path -type f -iname "*.jpg" -execdir convert {}  -resize 1024x1024\> -quality 70  {} \;`

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying the sips command again, it runs through as if it's doing something but doesn't seem to actually save the new file..? `find images/path -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec sips -Z 1024 -s format jpeg -s formatOptions 80  {} \;`

Comment: @Quadrant6 check if it's not saving the file in current directory, also test the sips command alone in the same path but specifying the full pathname for a test image file.

Comment: perfect to remove files: find "FOLDER_NAME" -type f -name '*_16.png' -exec rm {} \;
Thanks!!!!!

Comment: @Guilherme You can use `-delete` instead of `-exec rm {} \;` if you want just to remove files:

`find "FOLDER_NAME" -type f -name '*_16.png' -delete`

Answer (score 2):

I managed to change a small bash script which worked for me

```
#!/bin/bash

find "foldername" -type f | \
while read file ; do
    echo "processing ${file}"
    sips -Z 2000 ${file}
done
```